# Bootstrap + popover - skype href links not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following **PHP** + **HTML**:

```
                <div class="row justify-content-center" id="grid">
                    <?php
                    $result = $conn->query("SHOW TABLES from vmvelevp_roster");
                    while($tableName = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                        $table = $tableName[0];
                        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $table";
                        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
                        echo '<figure class="picture-item mr-2">';
                        echo '<img src="img/employees-img/' . $row['picname'] . '" ';
                        echo 'class="img-fluid rounded-circle" ';
                        echo 'data-toggle="popover" ';
                        echo 'data-placement="bottom" ';
                        echo 'title="' . $row['name'] . '" ';
                        echo "data-content='";
                        if (!empty($row['position'])) {
                            echo "<b>Position:</b> " . $row['position'] . "<br />";
                        }
                        if (!empty($row['department'])) {
                            echo "<b>Department:</b> " . $row['department'] . "<br />";
                        }
                        if (!empty($row['email'])) {
                            echo "<b>E-Mail:</b> <a href=mailto:" . $row['email'] .">" . $row['email'] . "</a><br />";
                        }
                        if (!empty($row['phoneinternal'])) {
                            echo "<b>Phone Internal:</b> " . $row['phoneinternal'] . "<br />";
                        }
                        if (!empty($row['phoneexternal'])) {
                            echo "<b>Phone External:</b> " . $row['phoneexternal'] . "<br />";
                        }
                        if (!empty($row['skype'])) {
                            echo "<b>Skype:</b> " . $row['skype'];
                            echo '<a href="skype:charie.brown?chat">Chat</a>';
                            echo "' ";
                        } else {
                            echo "' ";
                        }
                        echo 'alt="...">';
                        echo '<div class="picture-item__details">';
                        echo '<figcaption class="picture-item__title">' . $row['name'] . '</figcaption>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</figure>';
                    }
                }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

The email **href** is displayed perfectly, but the skype href is not being displayed.

I was wondering how can I fix this?

**My javascript regarding the popovers:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).popover({
            html: true,
            trigger: "manual"
        });
    }).on('mouseenter', function() {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover('show');
        $('.popover').on('mouseleave', function() {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!$('.popover:hover').length) {
                $(_this).popover('hide');
            }
        }, 50);
```

And this is my result:

[image]

Is there a way I can fix this?

It is strange because the **href** works when there is an email, but does not work when it is a skype link. I tried posting the code in a different file (only the hrefs) with the PHP connecting to my database and it works perfectly.

**EDIT:**
Just a brief explanation. The exact code that should be rendered for a single thing is:

```
<img src="img/employees-img/xxx.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-content="<b>Position:</b> xxx<br /><b>Department:</b> xxx<br /><b>E-Mail:</b> <a href=mailto:peter@xxx.com>peter@xxx.com</a><br /><b>Phone External:</b> +xxx<br /><a href="skype:charie.brown?chat">Chat</a>" alt="..." data-original-title="xxx">
```

If I paste this in a different document, the **href** is working.

Comment: It looks like you are not reading what the problem is. The href is not being displayed, not because it's not a valid link. The link is valid and should be displayed, and is displayed on a different page, without the popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the newest version of Bootstrap includes a sanitizer for safe URLs and skype is not one of them. You can read more information about this [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer)

In order to fix this, you have the options available on the link above or, you can edit the bootstrap.bundle.js as follows:

Change this:

```
var SAFE_URL_PATTERN = /^(?:(?:https?|mailto|ftp|tel|file):|[^&:/?#]*(?:[/?#]|$))/gi;
```

To this:

```
var SAFE_URL_PATTERN = /^(?:(?:https?|mailto|skype|ftp|tel|file):|[^&:/?#]*(?:[/?#]|$))/gi;
```

Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable HTML of your popover.

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover"><a href="skype:atic.chwdhry?chat">test</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html:true});   
});
</script>
```

Comment: As you can see in my code, I already have HTML enabled

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).popover({
            html: true,

Comment: I have made a change in my code. IN popover you just need to to enable html. Then in main ANCHOR tag you can put HTML of anything. I hope that helps.

Comment: this is not a solution, unfortunately. Check my edit (in the question). I have to have an img with data-content="and here goes the skype href".